# `while` is hanging

Tags: debugging

```lisp
    (defun test (n)
      (let ((list1 ()))
        (while (< (length list1) 10))
        (push (random n) list1)
        list1))
```

I'm trying to add `(random n)` to `list1` while the `length` of `list1` is less than 10. When I evaluate this function, it hangs. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You closed your `while` loop before doing the `push`.  So the list length stayed less than 10.

```lisp
(defun test (n)
  (let ((list1 ()))
    (while (< (length list1) 10)
      (push (random n) list1))
    list1))
```

**Moral:** Indent your code properly.  `C-M-q` is your friend, as is `TAB`.  See the Emacs manual, node [Indenting Several Lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multi_002dline-Indent.html).

Hanging should have been your clue that the `while` loop was infinite.  That would tell you that the list length wasn't increasing.

Comment: Great, thanks! I didn't know about `C-M-q` I was trying fo find a package to do proper indentation.

Comment: You're welcome. `C-h m` is your friend. In `emacs-lisp-mode` it mentions `C-M-q` (though admittedly it doesn't say much about it). You can look up its command (`indent-pp-sexp` in the Emacs manual, using `C-h S`). That takes you [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multi_002dline-Indent.html).